# Convert a one-row table to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider a table:

```r
ta <- structure(c(`0` = 1L, `2` = 3L, `4` = 4L, `5` = 2L), .Dim = 4L, .Dimnames = list(
    x = c("0", "2", "4", "5")), class = "table")

#> ta
# x
# 0 2 4 5 
# 1 3 4 2
```

With simple table, the conventional way (`as.data.frame.matrix`) does not seem to work:

```r
> as.data.frame.matrix(ta) 
Error in d[[2L]] : subscript out of bounds
```

So, is there an easy way to convert a table with one row to a data frame? So far, the only way I came up with is

```r
as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame.array(ta)))
   0 2 4 5
ta 1 3 4 2
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a 1d table, so convert to `list`

```
as.data.frame.list(ta, check.names = FALSE)
  0 2 4 5
1 1 3 4 2
```

With the OP's approach the `as.data.frame.matrix` can work if we do the `t`ranspose

```
as.data.frame.matrix(t(ta))
```

as the difference is in the addition of a second dimension

```
> str(ta)
 'table' int [1:4(1d)] 1 3 4 2
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ x: chr [1:4] "0" "2" "4" "5"
> str(t(ta))
 'table' int [1, 1:4] 1 3 4 2
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$  : NULL
  ..$ x: chr [1:4] "0" "2" "4" "5"
```

Answer (score 3):

Or another option is to use `rbind` with `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(rbind(ta), check.names = FALSE)

#   0 2 4 5
#ta 1 3 4 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- as_tibble(bind_rows(ta))
```

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  `0`     `2`     `4`     `5`    
  <table> <table> <table> <table>
1 1       3       4       2
```